# Set qTip2 direction from right to left (RTL)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, qtip2

I am using qTip2 and try to make the content of the tip right to left.

I add below css to `qtip` but the direction no worked:

text-align: right !important;
   direction: rtl !important;

and the js as below still not worked! Although `events` should be enough, I see some comments about using `onRender`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[title]').qtip({
        events: {
        render: function (event, api) {
            $(this).attr('dir', 'rtl');
        }
    },
    api: {
        onRender: function () {
            self.elements.content.rel('rtl');
        }
    },    
});

});
```

I found above codes from site support forum, but none of them helped me.

Please see sample at
http://jsfiddle.net/mnTCv/1/

Can you tell me how should I solve this issue?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must change this `.qtip-content` :

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/mnTCv/3/)

```
.qtip-content {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 9px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: right;   /*  default: left  */
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi: check new link

Answer (score 0):

I have added a div element and gave it a CSS style to be applied on the tooltip
... Here is a **[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/J2jaq/) (Arabic text inside)**

## CSS

```
div *, .qtip, .qtip-tip{direction:rtl !important; text-align:right !important; }
.qtip, .qtip-tip{ width:450px; }
```